# URL encoding the space character

Tags: php, jquery-pagination

Someone pls help me.  I have search form and displaying data from database and im using jquery twbsPagination. So my problem is the space in url if the user search two or more words.I used *encodeURIComponent();* its work perfectly fine its display data. but when i click on page 2. its display no data and when i go back to the first page the datas is not showing anymore. help me pls. im debugging for 12 hrs sorry for my english. 
this is my form

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <input id="searchBar" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search job">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button id="searchBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-flat">Go!</button>
            </span>
        </div>
```

and this is my script

```
<script>
 function Pagination(){
<?php
  $limit=5;
  $sql="SELECT COUNT(id_jobpost) AS id from job_post";
  $result=$conn->query($sql);
  if($result->num_rows > 0)
  {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $total_records = $row['id'];
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);
  } else {
    $total_pages = 1;
  }
?>
$('#pagination').twbsPagination({
  totalPages: <?php echo $total_pages;?>,
  visible: 5,
  onPageClick: function(e, page){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".target-content").html("Loading....");
    $(".target-content").load("job-pagination.php?page="+page);
  }
});
}
</script>

<script>
 $(function(){
  Pagination();
 });
</script>

<script>
$("#searchBtn").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var searchResult = $("#searchBar").val();
  var filter = "searchBar";
  if (searchResult != "") {
    $('#pagination').twbsPagination('destroy');
    Search(searchResult,filter);
  }else{
    $('#pagination').twbsPagination('destroy');
    Pagination();
  }
});
```

```
<script>
      function Search(val,filter){
        $('#pagination').twbsPagination({
        totalPages: <?php echo $total_pages; ?>,
        visible: 5,
        onPageClick: function(e, page){
          e.preventDefault();
          val = encodeURIComponent(val);
          $(".target-content").html("Loading....");
          $(".target-content").load("search.php?page="+page+"&search="+val+"&filter="+filter);
        }
      });
      }
    </script>
```

and this is my search.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("db.php");
 $limit = 5;

 if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
   $page = $_GET['page'];
 }else{
    $page = 1;
 }

 $start_from = ($page-1) * $limit;
 $search = $_GET['search'];
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM job_post WHERE jobtitle LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY id_jobpost DESC LIMIT $start_from, $limit";
$result=$conn->query($sql);
       if ($result->num_rows>0) {
        while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM company WHERE id_company='$row[id_companyname]'";
                $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
                if($result1->num_rows > 0) {
                while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) 
                    {
       ?>

            <div class="attachment-block clearfix">
                <img class="attachment-img" src="uploads/logo/<?php echo $row1['logo']; ?>" alt="Attachment Image">
                <div class="attachment-pushed">
                  <h4 class="attachment-heading"><a href="view-job-post.php?id=<?php echo $row['id_jobpost']; ?>"><?php echo $row['jobtitle']; ?></a> <span class="attachment-heading pull-right">₱<?php echo $row['maximumsalary']; ?>/Month</span></h4>
                  <div class="attachment-text">
                      <div><strong><?php echo $row1['companyname']; ?> | <?php echo $row1['province'].",".$row1['city']; ?> | Experience Required(in years): <?php echo $row['experience']; ?></strong></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

       <?php
                }
            }
        }
       }else{
        echo "<center><strong>No Job Matched!</strong></center>";
       }
       $conn->close();
       ?>
```

Comment: Which issue are you trying to fix, going to page 2 or going back to page 1? You are open to SQL injections. You should parameterize the query.

Comment: this code display data from database but when i go to page 2 that suppose to display other data from database is not showing and when i go back again to the page 1 its not showing the data anymore

Comment: i have edited my code upthere

Comment: What happens when you just manually type the search information you have in the address bar?  For example, if you go to this page: search.php?page="+page+"&search="+val+"&filter="+filter but replace the variables with actual information, does it show what you expect?

Comment: didnt show the data

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in your search.php page code.  You need to change your ending limit.

```
 $limit = 5;

 if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
   $page = $_GET['page'];
 }else{
    $page = 1;
 }

 $start_from = ($page-1) * $limit;
 $search = $_GET['search'];
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM job_post WHERE jobtitle LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY id_jobpost DESC LIMIT $start_from, $limit";
```

When you are on the first page, you are doing: LIMIT 0, 5.  When you are on the second page, you are doing: LIMIT 5, 5.

I suggest:

```
$limit = 5;

if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
   $page = $_GET['page'];
}else{
    $page = 1;
}

$start_from = ($page-1) * $limit;
$end_at = $page * $limit;
$search = $_GET['search'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM job_post WHERE jobtitle LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY id_jobpost DESC LIMIT $start_from, $end_at";
```

However I also noticed that in your search page you are doing a query inside of a query, I think a better way to do this is with a join so you only hit the database once.  I don't know the structure of your database but the below code is an example of a better way to go about it so that you only hit the database once:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("db.php");
$page_size = 5;

if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
   $page = $_GET['page'];
}else{
    $page = 1;
}

$start_from = ($page-1) * $page_size;
$end_at = $page * $page_size;

$search = $_GET['search'];
$sql = "
  SELECT 
    j_p.*, 
    c.* 
  FROM 
    job_post j_p, 
    company c 
  WHERE 
    jobtitle LIKE '%$search%' 
    and c.id_company = j_p.id_companyname
  ORDER BY 
    id_jobpost DESC 
  LIMIT 
    $start_from, 
    $end_at
";
$result=$conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows>0) {
  while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
?>

  <div class="attachment-block clearfix">
    <img class="attachment-img" src="uploads/logo/<?php echo $row1['logo']; ?>" alt="Attachment Image">
    <div class="attachment-pushed">
      <h4 class="attachment-heading"><a href="view-job-post.php?id=<?php echo $row1['id_jobpost']; ?>"><?php echo $row1['jobtitle']; ?></a> <span class="attachment-heading pull-right">₱<?php echo $row1['maximumsalary']; ?>/Month</span></h4>
      <div class="attachment-text">
          <div><strong><?php echo $row1['companyname']; ?> | <?php echo $row1['province'].",".$row1['city']; ?> | Experience Required(in years): <?php echo $row1['experience']; ?></strong></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php
  }
}else{
  echo "<center><strong>No Job Matched!</strong></center>";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: okay okay. but still the data didnt show when i switch page the data only show once and its only in first page

Comment: i dont know if i can debug this :(

Comment: i know my problem sir. when i type to words example "project manager". at first the word "project manager" stored in variable and when i click to next page the value into "project%25manager" then when i click to another page the value becomes "project%2525manager" and so on . how can i get rid of that sir

Comment: i figured it out my problem atlast. i just need to decodeURIComponent my value. thanks

Comment: Awesome!  I'm glad you figured it out!